# Amazon Redshift - What is the default join?

Tags: join, amazon-redshift

What is the default "join" in Amazon Redshift? When I do not specify any direction, does Redshift use Inner or Left or Right or Outer join?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL which defaults on **INNER JOIN** same as many other query languages.

You can also find it out by creating two simple tables as following and executing a simple SELECT by JOIN query

> ```
> A    B
> -    -
> 1    3
> 2    4
> 3    5
> 4    6
> ```

```
select * from a JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
```

Here *1,2* are unique to table A and 5,6 are unique to table B while *3,4* being common
the query above returns only the values 3,4 so it's inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift, like pretty much all SQL databases, follow the SQL Standard.

It specifies that when join type is absent, it is equivalent to INNER JOIN

From the SQL Specification:

> If a < qualified join > or < natural join > is specified and a < join type >
>   is not specified, then INNER is implicit.